How to automatically reformat gradle project module dependicies from xxxxxx(":one:two:three") to xxxxxx(projects.one.two.three)
Our organisations large multi module android project has recently been migrated to employ version catalogue, build-logic and convention plugins.
all existing build gradle kts files were reformatted to use
enableFeaturePreview("TYPESAFE_PROJECT_ACCESSORS")

so that all module dependencies could be reformatted from
xxxxxxx(":aaaa:bbbb:cccc")

to
xxxxxxx(projects.aaaa.bbbb.cccc)

the issues we are facing now are that whenever new modules are added to the android project and configured as dependencies, Android Studio employs this format xxxxxxx(":aaaa:bbbb:cccc") and not xxxxxxx(projects.aaaa.bbbb.cccc).
how can we resolve this issue?
Can Android Studio be configured to use xxxxxxx(projects.aaaa.bbbb.cccc) format?
Or
can we add an extension function to org.gradle.api.Project to reformat (transform) this format xxxxxxx(":aaaa:bbbb:cccc") to the desired project accessor format of xxxxxxx(projects.aaaa.bbbb.cccc)
i can see the dependencies block
public fun org.gradle.api.Project.dependencies(configuration: org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.DependencyHandlerScope.() -> kotlin.Unit): kotlin.Unit { /* compiled code */ }

has a registerTransform
public open fun <T : org.gradle.api.artifacts.transform.TransformParameters?> registerTransform(actionType: java.lang.Class<out org.gradle.api.artifacts.transform.TransformAction<T>>, registrationAction: org.gradle.api.Action<in org.gradle.api.artifacts.transform.TransformSpec<T>>): kotlin.Unit { /* compiled code */ }

which looks like it could be a good candidate for "transforming" dependencies "from" this format xxxxxxx(":aaaa:bbbb:cccc") "to" the desired project accessor format of xxxxxxx(projects.aaaa.bbbb.cccc) however i am having difficulty in finding any examples to assist me in the development of such Transformation.
